# React - Accessing values in a JSON response

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

Im trying to access a value returned by an AXIOS request.
Here is the fetching function :

```
 function sendAddRequest(id) {
    const headers = {
      X_TPP: id,
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    };
    
    const agent = new https.Agent({
      rejectUnauthorized: false,
    });
    const response = Axios.get(
      "/Auth/v1/auth",
      { headers },
      { httpsAgent: agent }
    )
    .then((response) => setauthorizationLinks(JSON.stringify(response)))
    .catch((err) => console.error(err)); // promise;

    window.open(authorizationLinks);
  }
```

The response is in this shape :

[image]

I need to access the url returned and open it in a new tab.

[image: New tab link]

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting all the response including datat header ,  ...

you have only to access `response.data` then get the `url` , also open the `window.open` inside the response () :

```
const response = Axios.get(
      "/Auth/v1/auth",
      { headers },
      { httpsAgent: agent }
   )
   .then((response) => {
        setauthorizationLinks(response.data.url) 
        window.open(response.data.url);
   })
.catch((err) => console.error(err)); // promise;
```